# Forums about getting SQL Server 2000 Administration help?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

What I'm trying to accomplish is that I need to migrate the SQL Server 2000 installation into a  SQL Server 2008 installation, and I would like to say that I am afraid that after this operation I will be unable to use some of my database objects.

- What is the best (in your opinion) forum about MS SQL Server 2000 administration?
- Is it possible to ask hard questions and get professional answers at those forums you would recommend?

Comment: There is no "best forum" regarding SQL Server, you will find good quality answers in many places. It's just a matter of discerning good or bad, but that comes with experience.

Comment: @Marian "Good judgment comes from experience. Experience comes from bad judgment." eh?

Comment: welcome to the Database Administrators StackExchange site. Depending on if you want help going forward, or if you want to try and find help from existing solutions on the internet determines what are the better resources. This will almost certainly be your best, most timely, most accurate resource for answers going forward. If we're looking back in time, I can't imagine that you're going to be needing those old answers except for legacy maintenance. We're glad to see you here, and I for one hope that you will ask all your questions here for fast, timely, accurate answers. Welcome!

Answer (score 4):

This forum or ServerFault.

In the 13 years i've been working with SQL Server since 6.5 I've frequented several (SQL Server Central, SQL Server Performance etc) but it's hard to discern quality answers on these.

The reputation system on the Stack Exchange sites is a powerful tool to ensure higher quality answers as well weeding out the poor ones.

I can't understand your worries about upgrading: unless you have some code that (ab)uses sp_OA% or such you should be OK. The [Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f5a6c5e9-4cd9-4e42-a21c-7291e7f0f852) will assist you here

Comment: I'd put a star on SQL Server Central too. It saved my pants many many times. Even if they don't give perfect answer, there are at least ideas and directions.

Comment: @Marian: Agree, helped me too, but the rep system wins it for me nowadays

Comment: That's a better system, I agree with you. When people agree with you and create rep, then your solution has helped them too or they have the same idea. It's also easier to use by having the system of Q&A.